# How to expand environment variables from variable names in Python

Tags: python

At work we use `.pam_environment` to hold some of our paths to commonly used folders. For example:

```
PROJECTS DEFAULT=${HOME}/projects
APP_DIR = ${PROJECTS}/app_name
```

When I want to get that information with Python, I use the following code:

```
>>> import os
>>> app_dir = os.environ['APP_DIR']
${PROJECTS}/app_name
```

What I want to do is get the absolute path to `app_name` so I can run it with `subprocess`. However this is what happens when I attempt to do that:

```
>>> os.path.abspath('${PROJECTS}/app_name')
'/current_working_directory/${PROJECTS}/app_name'
```

This is an invalid path and the subprocess call will fail. I know I can set `subprocess`'s `shell=True` to make it work, but I was hoping there was a way to get a valid path without doing that in case I need that path for other work in the application.

Note: We use Python 2.7 at work.

Comment: Good call. I hunted all over for that on Google yesterday and couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. I rewrote an env. variable evaluator instead of using that because I didn't know about it! now I can inject custom non-environment variables into it though so it wasn't a waste of time.